# Power Cleans; They benefit my back?

Tags: compound-exercises, power-cleans

Can someone explain to me how do Power Cleans strengthen my back? I feel it but I can't understand how it works, or how if most of my movement is with my legs how it can affect/stress my back. I still do them, although I don't completely understand them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a power clean you are supposed to keep your back straight and to lift it upright against the bar pulling you forward and down. Your lower and middle back is held rigid to keep the trunk stable. Your upper back retracts your shoulder blades to keep the bar close to your body, and at the end of the pull, your upper back explosively shrugs the bar upward.

Comment: Well that makes a lot of sense!!! Thank you for helping clearing my doubt